# select last child in list not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list but use `<p>`, it look like this

```
<p class="title">
<p>

<p class="title>
<p>

<p class="title>
<p>
```

so I used

```
.title + P to apply `margin-bottom: 20px;`
```

then I wish to remove the last p, by 
`.title + P:last-child` to apply margin zero, but it doesn't work

Comment: check your HTML, missing closing `"` for class.  Might be a problem too.

Comment: So you want it to look something like this? But im guessing you cant do it this way? [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9RmTr/1)

Comment: Where is there a list? I see 3 paragraphs

Comment: Why does this question have 3 upvotes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target with p and ten class name

Try `p.title:last-child`

In your html closing tag for `p` is missing that is the reason it is unable to identify `p` tag at all. And wrap p with a div.

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iYOYOniJ/4/)**

Comment: `<p>` doesn't need closing tags (unless in specific circumstances, but not here).

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use [last-of-type](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/):

```
.title + p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

#### Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ppLGv/

Read about the difference between `last-child` and `last-of-type` at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
p:last-child {
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```